# This .XLSX connection string does not seem to work even with multiple modifications

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oledb, oledbconnection

I know there are several resources out there on ACE OLEDB connection strings for .xlsx files.

This is my current connection string:

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + uploadFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";
```

I tried

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + uploadFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;\"";
```

Also tried

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + uploadFilePath + ";Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

I have tried several on connectionstrings.com and also from stackoverflow

Usually my errors are

```
{"External table is not in the expected format."}
```

or

```
{"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 118."}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions on the right connection string to use? .xls files are working just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello my friend please take a look in to my connection string :

mainFolder is a path to folder example : C:\Users\username\Desktop\Main
comboboxtext is full name of excel file example : SomeSample.xlsx

```
 using (OleDbConnection connection =
                         new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + mainFolder + "" + @"\" + comboBox2.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\""))
```